# How to group string values using the calculated field in tableau prep

Tags: function, grouping, tableau-api

I would like to group string values but I always got syntax error.

Here's what I would like to achieve:
I have a position column contains values like accountant, finance, IT, HR, admin and so on. But I am only interested in those who are in HR position. therefore I would like to group HR related position and non-HR related positions.

I tried using if, contains and or function but failed.

here's my code:

```
IF (CONTAINS([Position],“HR”) OR

(CONTAINS([Position],“hr”)  OR

(CONTAINS([Position],“Human Resource”) OR

(CONTAINS([Position],“ Human Resource ”)


THEN "HR-Related" 
ELSE "Non-HR Related"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Each of the opening brackets need a corresponding closing bracket. You could either

```
(CONTAINS([Position],"HR"))
```

to ensure 2 opening and 2 closing brackets, or perhaps a cleaner example would be to remove the initial opening bracket

```
CONTAINS([Position],"HR")
```

This example also highlights a small but important difference between a **double quotation mark - " "** and a set of **left double quotation mark and right double quotation mark - “ ”**.

Tableau will not accept left/right quotation marks (UNICODE U+201C and U+201D) for defining a string value as done `CONTAINS([Position],“HR”)`. It will accept a string value for double quotation mark (UNICODE U+0022) as done in `"HR-Related"`.

The following formula should resolve the syntax errors:

```
IF 
CONTAINS([Position],"HR") OR
CONTAINS([Position],"hr")  OR
CONTAINS([Position],"Human Resource") OR
CONTAINS([Position]," Human Resource " )
THEN "HR-Related"
ELSE "Non-HR Related"
END
```

Comment: @jifahf You may also find value in learning about the REGEXP_MATCH() function for pattern matching in strings. Also note, your final condition will never trigger because the third condition would already be satisfied for any matching string.